# jquery: passing parameters and initial function to jquery prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, chaining

I am new to this site and new to jQuery.

I want to use a so-called [bootstrap material datetime picker](https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker), which allows you to assign a plugin to an HTML input-element. When there is an `onfocus` event for this element, the picker wakes and is shown on the screen in overlay mode. After selecting a date from the picker, the picker disappears and the value of the HTML variable is set to the selected value.

I want the picker to display without interaction with the HTML input variable; also, the user should be able to change the value of the HTML input element without using the picker. My problem is that I cannot pass the initial parameters AND the function to the plugin.

Normally the plugin is used in this way:

```
$('#_Date_5').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker();  // this works
```

Parameters can be passed like this

```
$('#_Date_5').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker(
    {
        format: '<format>',
        shortTime: false,
        minDate: null,
        maxDate: null,
        currentDate: null,
        date: true,
        time: true,
        clearButton: true,
        nowButton: true,
        switchOnClick: false,
        triggerEvent: 'focus'
    } 
);
```

If I want a function (let us say `_fireCalendar()`) to be called when the plugin is initialized, then I could use the following:

```
$('#_Date_5').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker('_fireCalendar');
```

Now I am using an interim HTML variable to provide the desired initial datetime value to the picker and bind the picker to this interim variable. The picker should be shown after clicking on a iconic symbol right to the editable value. Now the user can edit the value without using the picker or decide to use the picker alternatively.

Now to my problem - **Is it possible to pass *both* a set of parameters *and* a callback function upon initialisation**

I have managed to achieve this by calling `_fireCalender()` within the plugin's constructor, however I'd like to be able to do it without modifying the plugin itself.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

okay - here is my solution - nasty ( the plugin code needed to be changed ) - but working:

1. added new Parameter this.params.beforeHiding to the constructor of the plugin. the parameter beforeHiding is initially set to null and can be set to a function
2. called the function passed by this.params.beforeHiding at the end of the method hide()

in the constructor

```
this.params = {beforeHiding:null, <original parameters>}
```

in the method hide()

```
if ( this.params.beforeHiding !== null ) this.params.beforeHiding();
```

this code will use the new functionality:

```
var date_interim = document.getElementById('var_interim');
var date_original = document.getElementById('_Date_5');

date_interim.value = date_original.value;

$('#var_interim').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker(
{
format: '<format>',
shortTime: false,
date: true,
time: false,
clearButton: true,
nowButton: true,
switchOnClick: false,
triggerEvent: 'focus',
beforeHiding: function()
{
var date_interim = document.getElementById('var_interim');
var date_original = document.getElementById('_Date_5');
date_original.value = date_interim.value;
}
}
);

// display the picker by focussing it
date_interim.focus();
```

The code is bound to he click event of a HTML image tag and uses an interim-variable, which is a HTML input field and the user can both edit the original value manually or pick a value from the picker. Focussing the interim variable shows the picker on the screen.